# What's wrong with my HTML code to create multiple markers in Google's places api?

Tags: html, api

I'm trying to create multiple markers for my website and I'm having two problems. First, I can't actually get the code to work functionally and second I'm trying to augment the infowindows and I can't seem to make them large. Any help? I'm an amateur so I feel like it's something I overlooked I appreciate the assistance.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>

var markers = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
];

function initializeMaps() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)
;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Should be

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMaps);
```

and

```
document.getElementById("map_canvas")
```

Should be

```
document.getElementById("googleMap")
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1ymp60rt/)

Comment: I knew I overlooked something! Thank you much TJ!